# Rails 3 Routing to Add String to Home URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-rewriting

Using Rails 3 routing, I'd like all visitors to the home page

```
http//mysite.com/
```

to see the URL

```
http//mysite.com/mykeyword
```

in their browser URL.

In other words, all visits to the home page get redirected to

```
http//mysite.com/mykeyword
```

This is approximately the opposite of the typical route

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

or

```
match '/' => 'home#index'
```

where any controller name gets stripped off from the home page URL.

Instead I want every visit to the site home page to include "mykeyword" in the URL.

**How?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Justin is correct, but I believe you also want a redirect. To do that:

```
match "/" => redirect("/mykeyword")
```

Comment: ahh yeah, I was trying to figure out that part :P

Comment: Jarret's answer is complete. It looks like this:
   
 match '/mykeyword' => "home#index"
 
 match "/" => redirect("/mykeyword")
 
 # root :to => 'home#index'
 
Note: It fails if "root :to => 'home#index'" precedes the other routes.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you need `root :to => 'home#index'` as long as you are already matching `/` to your homepage with a redirect.

Comment: Justin, that's correct, which is why I showed it as commented out. In case someone thinks it is still needed. Thanks for the clarifying that point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
match '/mykeyword' => "home#index"
```

You want visitors to still be on the homepage, but the url to say "www.mysite.com/mykeyword" right? If so, that should work.

Comment: Not quite. It displays the home page for http//mysite.com/mykeyword but visitors to http//mysite.com/ still see "http//mysite.com/" without any additional string. I want all visitors to http//mysite.com/ to see "http//mysite.com/mykeyword" (force appending the additional string).

Comment: yeah, then combine my code with Jarrett's code and that should give you your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Justin, for getting the ball rolling with your contribution.